# Attaching Multiple Files to an email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Been stuck on this all day and am not really sure what the issue is.  I've read through everything I could find in the forums which have gotten me closer but not quite there yet.

Here's what going on.  Our web site uses phpMailer.  We are trying to allow a applicant to upload 2 files via our contact form.  Here is a sample of the code.

```
<td><span class="csr-contact-field">Resume*</span></td>
<td>
    <input type="file" name="resume[]" id="resume" value="<?php if(isset($Resume)) echo $Resume ?>" multiple />
    <br />
    <span class="csr-form-error">
        <?php if (isset($errors['fileError'])) echo $errors['fileError']; ?>
    </span>
</td>

<?php
if ($Page == "careers.php") {
    $target_dir = "upload\\";
    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "txt", "rtf");
    $names = $_FILES["resume"]["name"];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "$name\n";
        $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($name);
        echo "What's here ---- $target_file\n";
        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
            if ($_FILES["resume"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
                $errors['fileError'] = "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileError"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else {
                if (file_exists($target_file)) { 
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file);
                }
                else {
                    $errors['fileError']= "File Does Not Exist!";
                }
                $mail->AddAttachment($target_file);
                $i++;
            }   
        }
        else {
            $errors['fileError'] = "Please submit a valid file type (doc, docx, pdf, txt, rtf).";
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

When I go to attach a file I get an error telling me the file does not exist, but even if I use the full path and confirm the file location by printing out the variable, it still gives me that error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: yea, even with the full path specified it throws the error, it's almost as if it doesn't try to upload the file at all

Comment: how can a file exists before you move it? there is no point in checking this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I solved it with all your help using the following code changes

```
<?php
if ($Page == "careers.php") {
    $target_dir = 'upload\\';
    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "txt", "rtf");
    $names = $_FILES["resume"]["name"];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($names as $name) {
        $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($name);
        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
            if ($_FILES["resume"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
                $errors['fileError'] = "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileError"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file);
                if (file_exists($target_file)) { 
                    $mail->AddAttachment($target_file);
                }
                else {
                    $errors['fileError']= "File Does Not Exist!";
                }

            }   
        }

        else {
            $errors['fileError'] = "Please submit a valid file type (doc, docx, pdf, txt, rtf).";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

The only issue that remains is that the files remain in my upload directory once they are sent.  Any suggestions on handling that?

Comment: Nevermind, I had it in my code with the wrong variable name.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not right. You are checking if the target file exist, but it doesn't exist yet since you are going to create it on the next line.

Most likely what you want is:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"][$i]))
```

But even that is not really necessary because if this tmp_name field is populated it means PHP definitely has the file there.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a snippet from my project;
But the basic idea of the following approach stores attachment filepaths in an array and iterate through it.

```
           // 4.3 attachements
            if(isset($configuration[$filepath]) 
                 and $configuration[$filepath]] != null 
                 and $configuration[$filepath]] != '')
            {
                $array = explode(',', $configuration[$filepath]);

                if(is_array($array) and !empty($array))
                {
                    foreach($array as $file)
                    {
                        if(isset($file) and $file != null and $file != '')
                        {
                            $mail->AddAttachment($file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps.